# The method update(String) from the type RequestContext is deprecated

Tags: java, primefaces

When I use next code part in my code : 
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("growl");

there is a warning as "The method update(String) from the type RequestContext is deprecated" and in code part and crossed of "update".

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("growl");
```

there is a warning as "The method update(String) from the type RequestContext is deprecated" and in code part and crossed of "update".

It is clear that  this way is overdue. What is the modern way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been replaced with:

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(expressions);
```

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/7_0
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/ajax/rendering?id=dynamicruntime-updates

Comment: Which even is in the update/migration documentation... more and more developers become lazy in not following things,