# when I am updating Pirmefaces version from 5.2 to 6.2 some JUnit test cases are getting failed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I updated version of primefaces from 5.2 to 6.2 then  I am getting JUnit test cases are getting failed. Whenever reverting 6.2 to 5.2 JUnit test cases are passing successfully.

I guess below kind of line is giving error

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('editMyContact').hide();");`

Comment: **What** is the error? Did you post the error in a search engine and tried to find a a solution. And  please make the title more specific regarding the error...

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('editMyContact').hide();");

this line was giving the error

Answer (score 2):

Before just updating a library, always check the migration guide ;) https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

RequestContext is deprecated/removed in favor of PrimeFaces.current();

Comment: The reason I asked what the error is, is that there are duplicates of this in Stackoverflow already (always checking this before posting is a good thing ;-)).  And 'deprecated' != removed... So API wise I expected it to still work in 6.2 (as the 6.2 api docs still contains them).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285566/primefaces-requestcontext-under-7-0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309757/the-method-updatestring-from-the-type-requestcontext-is-deprecated